# What is the name for enum kind values within a REST api context?

Tags: rest, terminology

Suppose there is a REST API where one of the parameter values can be "Type A", "Type B"  or "Type C".
In normal programming the parameter would be of Enum type, and it would be easy to look up the possible values.

In rest API, not unless extra documentation is provided one can not know the allowed values, my question is what is the name for such type of parameters? In contrast int parameters are easy to provide value for ( Unless that too is suppose to be some specific values only ).

Are there any tools that in addition to generating metadata for for service (Like ServiceStack does) can also generate info about allowed values for service parameters?